# Read values from text field individually

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I would like to read all values from a text field/text box individually and then write them to a table:

Example:

```
This is an example of a text I want to read out.
```

Output:

1. This
2. is
3. an
4. example
5. of
6. a
7. text
8. I
9. want
10. to
11. read
12. out

How can I use a loop to read the text field/textbox?
That is, whenever a space comes the new subsequent value must be in a new line.

Comment: [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**String:**

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var phrase = "This is an example of a text I want to read out";

var words = phrase.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  var tableCol = 
  `<tr>
    <td>${i+1}:</td>
    <td>${words[i].replace(/[\.,!\?]/g," ")}<td>
  </tr>`;
  
  document.querySelector('table tbody').innerHTML += tableCol;
}
```

```css
#table {
  border: 1px solid;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Number:</th>
    <th>Word:</th>
  <thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Input:**

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");

myBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = '';
  var phrase = myInput.value;
  var words = phrase.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var tableCol = 
    `<tr>
      <td>${i+1}:</td>
      <td>${words[i].replace(/[\.,!\?]/g," ")}<td>
    </tr>`;

    document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML += tableCol;
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
}

#table {
  border: 1px solid;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button id="myBtn">Create Table</button>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Number:</th>
    <th>Word:</th>
  <thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You missed the punctuation

Answer (score 0):

Shorter and removing punctuation

```js
const str = `This is an example of a text I want to read out.`;

document.querySelector('table tbody').innerHTML = str.split(" ")
  .map((word,i) => `<tr><td>${i+1}:</td><td>${word.replace(/[\.,!\?]/g,"")}<td></tr>`)
  .join("");
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Number:</th>
    <th>Word:</th>
  <thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```